# Flask-wtf upload file error

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

Following https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/blob/v0.9.4/docs/form.rst
First, I get an error message that "Error in the Project contract field - None". If I remove "validators=[FileRequired(), FileAllowed(['pdf'], 'Pdf only!')])" part, I got another error message 'unicode' object has no attribute 'filename'

```
    proj_contract = FileField('Project contract'), validators=[FileRequired(), FileAllowed(['pdf'], 'Pdf only!')])

    <form method="POST" action="{{url_for('.new_project')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        {{form.proj_contract.label}}:<input type="file" value="Upload"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Next" name="Next">
    </form> 

    def new_project():
        projectInfoForm = ProjectInfoForm(request.form)
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return render_template('application/project/projectinfo.html', form = projectInfoForm)
        else:
            if projectInfoForm.validate_on_submit():
                c_filename = secure_filename(projectInfoForm.proj_contract.data.filename)
projectInfoForm.proj_contract.file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], c_filename))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
projectInfoForm = ProjectInfoForm(request.form)
```

to

```
projectInfoForm = ProjectInfoForm()
```

flask-wtf fills the form with data from request.form and request.files automatically. If you pass request.form, it will only process that and wont fill the form with request.files.

Comment: Your suggestion didn't change anything.